# Object input not found - R flexdashboard

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I am having some issues making a dashboard with flexdashboard and shiny in R. The idea is plotting the data based on a filter that I run before plotting using the tidyverse library.

I have problems with `selectInput()`, since when I run the code subtracting it from it I get the dashboard, but when I include it I get this error:

```
Error in `filter()`:
ℹ In argument: `modulo == input$modulo_`.
Caused by error:
! object 'input' not found
```

Here is the code I have been developing:

````
---
title: "PUDA2022: Discovering clustering patterns"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)

load("clustersData.RData")
```


Distribución Económica
=======================================================================
Sidebar {.sidebar}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

```{r}
selectInput(inputId = "modulo_",
            label =  "Modulo",
            choices = unique(mEcon$modulo),
            #choices = c("Laundry","BodyWashing","Toilet Use","Hand Washing",
            #            "Brushing Teeth","Dishwashing"),
            selected = "Laundry")

```

Column {data-width=450}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

```{r}
##preparamos los datos
m1_economic_contribucion<-mEcon %>% filter(modulo==input$modulo_) %>% group_by(cluster,`V9. PAGO_AGUA`) %>% summarise(Freq=n())


m1_economic_ingreso<-mEcon %>% filter(modulo==input$modulo_) %>% group_by(cluster,ClaseSocial) %>% summarise(Freq=n())


```

### Cluster 1: Contribución al pago del agua

```{r}
m1_economic_contribucion %>%
  filter(cluster==1) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=`V9. PAGO_AGUA`,y=Freq))+
  geom_bar(stat='identity',fill="#7AC5CD")+
  labs(x = " ")
```

### Cluster 1: Clase social por ingreso del hogar

```{r}
m1_economic_ingreso %>%
  filter(cluster==1) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=ClaseSocial,y=Freq))+
  geom_bar(stat='identity',fill="#7AC5CD")+
  labs(x = " ")

```
````

What am I overlooking?

Comment: The value of an `input` can only be accessed within a `reactive()`, a `renderXXX()` function or an `observe()`r. I would suggest to have a look at the basics of `shiny` and reactivity, e.g. https://mastering-shiny.org/basic-reactivity.html#basic-reactivity

Comment: To build on the comment by@stefan, the lines using "##preparamos los datos
m1_economic_contribucion<-mEcon %>% filter(modulo==input$modulo_) are outside of that reactive context. That code would only work within the server.